# Eliminating carriage returns from a CSV file in PHP

Tags: php, csv

I'm trying to write a php file to eliminate carriage returns in a CSV file.  I am trying to first read from the original CSV file containing the carriage returns in column 1.  Next, trim or eliminate the carriage returns and then write the corrected string into a new CSV file. But I'm having some trouble on how to specifically do that. I received an error on this program and I'm not sure what's the problem with this code.
What am I missing here?  Any suggestions?

Here is my original code:

```
<?php
$file_read = fopen('testCarriageFile.csv', "r");
$file_write = fopen('testCarriageFile2.csv', "w+");
while(!feof($file_read)) {
    $file_trim = trim($file_read, "\r");
    fwrite($file_write, $file_trim);
}
fclose($file_read);
fclose($file_write);
?>
```

Comment: You aren't actually reading from the file... after the feof and before the trim, you need something like an fgets or fread. Additionally that var should be what you pass in to "trim" not the file handle.

Answer (score 1):

You are not reading anything from the file. You need to use `fgets` or `fgetcsv` for CSV files. Try this:

```
while(!feof($file_read)) {
    $file_line = fgets($file_read);
    $file_trim = trim($file_line, "\r");
    fwrite($file_write, $file_trim);
}
```

Not sure why you are removing carriage returns when you could just use `fgetcsv` to read CSV file and if you are not sure about line endings use `ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);`

Comment: +1 for [`fgetcsv()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php). I get the feeling that OP is trying to modify data in a field that *contains* line breaks because either what's writing the CSV is not escaping/enclosing strings properly, or what's reading the CSV is not taking escapes/enclosures into account.